# Can't get wrong sender name from appearing -- only when sending from iphone

Tags: iphone, email, gmail

I have several email accounts that I send and receive from -- either on my iPhone 6s or on my laptop. One email account is for business & one is for personal. When an email from the business email account is sent *from my phone*, the wrong name is listed as the sender (my former assistant's name) -- but only when sent from my business email account on my phone.  When I email from my business email on my laptop, it is listed as from my business name (which is how I want it).

Also, strangely enough, when I send an email on the phone from the business email to my personal email and open it in my personal email account ON MY PHONE, it appears correctly as from my business name (that's the only time it looks right when sent from the phone business email account). BUT if I open this same email in personal email account on my laptop, it's wrong. And anyone else who gets something from the business email, it is wrong (again, only if sent from my phone).

When I do a search on the phone in contacts app under the business email address, the business name correctly comes up. When I do a search under the former assistant's name, it comes up empty.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get her name off as the sender!  I use an iPhone 6S, most recent iOS version (11-something, I think), and I have a plan with Verizon. I access my email via google gmail.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something or misunderstand the question, but it seems to me the reason for this has nothing to do with your iPhone. Instead, it's most likely related to where the email address is recorded in the contacts on your laptop and on devices belonging to other people.

I'll try and clarify my answer with an example scenario:

- Let's say an email address is used by Fred Flintsone. You and others add Fred Flintstone to your various Contact lists on your various devices and add the email address to that contact.
- Fred Flintstone retires and then Pebbles Flintstone takes over and assumes the same email address. She uses an iPhone and adds the email account to her settings and uses her name. So now the email address, on her iPhone, appears with her name.
- However, Pebbles also uses the laptop that Fred used previously. In this laptop the email address is still listed under Fred's details in the contacts. So, if an email comes into the inbox on this laptop, it appears as though it's come from Fred Flintstone because that's who the email is associated with.
- Likewise, if anyone else still has that email address associated with Fred Flintstone in their contact lists, the same thing will happen.

Assuming that your scenario is *something* like the above, then the answer is to ensure that the email address is associated **only** with you, not with your former assistant and not with both you and the former assistant on their contact lists.

**NOTE:** This scenario does not apply in all scenarios (e.g. with a MS Exchange account, etc) but does apply in *most* situations.

Comment: I appreciate your response.  I checked the contacts in my personal and business accounts on my laptop to see if my former assistant's name is there, but it isn't.  It's possible your point might apply to others we send email to (if they have my old assistant's name with my business email address in their contacts), but I'm not sure it explains why this only happens when the original business email is generated from my phone & not from my laptop (or from my new assistant's devices).  I know it's a crazy situation & appreciate your input, though.

Comment: Ah, I see. I *thought* I may have missed something! :( You're right, my answer *may* explain part of the problem in relation to others, but certainly not all of it. Have you checked Settings > Accounts & Passwords to see if this account is listed there? If so, does tapping on it reveal anything useful (e.g. your former assistant's name)? Also, just for clarity, when you say *I access my email via google gmail*, do you just mean it's a gmail address you're accessing via the Mail app, or do you mean you're using one of Goggle's apps to send/receive your emails from your iPhone?